# Cannot use webRequest on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new in Chrome Extension development.

I have the following permissions in manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "tabs",
  "webNavigation",
  "management",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*"
]
```

Also background entry and background.js file

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": true
},
```

This background.js is included in popup.html head

```
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

And the problem is I can't add a listener in background.js script

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener

I get the error **background.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined.**

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: do read well the documentation about what is a background page. you are mixing popup with background, marking to close as simple error.

Comment: @ZigMandel, popup page and background page both live in the context of the extension, so to my knowledge, it's ok to register `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` in `popup.html`.

Comment: @Ashot Khachatryan, could you please provide your `background.js`?

Comment: certainly not by including the background.js script inside popup.html.

Comment: As a general rule, if you are using the very same script for the background page and the popup - _you're doing it wrong_. Some code certainly can be shared, but otherwise this smells of error.